# How can I create frontend for Spring microservice with gRPC on backend?

Tags: spring, grpc, grpc-java

I have a question: how can I manually develop frontend for Spring microservice, which has rest controller, and grpc controller? I can understand, how it works with rest controllers, but how it may work with grpc I haven't any idea. Please, help me. I have questions about mapping, and how it is should interacts with html client.
approximate scheme: db => service => grpc controller (which implements rpc methods from proto file) => frontend
How can I provide frontend client for grpc controller?

Comment: Your question is quite broad, you would better ask something more precise if you want Stack Overflow community to help...

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by grpc controller. Do you mean (1) a grpc server or (2) a rest controller which has a grpc client talking to some grpc backend? For (1), you may try https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter. For (2), the front end client is still a rest client, and a request from the front end client will trigger the rest controller to start a grpc client talking to the grpc backend and then to render the grpc response from the backend to a html/json response, and then to send the response to the front end client.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends upon your project requirements but for Ideal scenario:
You need minimum two microservices one is GRPC server side in which you'll have your business logic and DB integration and 2nd for GRPC client side as well as Spring MVC Controllers.

Flow will be:

**(GRPC-Client-Microservice)**
UI -> Spring MVC Controllers -> Service layer (It'll have client of GRPC-Server-Microservice to call GRPC-APIs)

**(GRPC-Server-Microservice)**
@GrpcService -> @Service -> @Repository -> DB

I hope it will answer your question, If you still need more details let me know I'll create above example and share with you.

It's just for basic understanding related to gRPC but for production we should use [Envoy Proxy](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/web/basics/#configure-the-envoy-proxy) to convert http to gRPC or wise vers.
There are alos couple of [altenatives](https://stackshare.io/envoy/alternatives) available

We need this conversion becasue most of the browsers still not supporting gRPC. But between microservices communication it's highly recommended to use gRPC (server and client) commnunication even with blocking stub.

Comment: Hello @Az.MaYo I have this application in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410367/i-created-a-grpc-with-spring-boot-using-libraries-from-the-io-grpc-repository)spring grpc and I'm not sure if it's right. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: @RafaelSouza I have updated my answer to guide you more. and I think you need to know more about basics related to gRPC.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Az.MaY, tell me something in kubernetes, creating pods, does grpc already work natively? In my case it's an api in spring boot for android jetpack compose. Another doubt for web app I call the grpc client in my controller same as in my example?

Comment: 1) Yes

2)  For web I don't know what you are using but we can create gRPC client in JavaScript, please have a look on [this article](https://medium.com/sessionstack-blog/implementation-of-grpc-in-a-nodejs-8ea8c4cdb9eb#:~:text=The%20Concept%20of%20gRPC&text=And%20this%20is%20the%20where,can%20run%20in%20any%20environment.) you can find [official doc](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/node/basics/) as well.

Comment: I am using spring boot like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410367/i-created-a-grpc-with-spring-boot-using-libraries-from-the-io-grpc-repository) @Az.MaYo Thanks.