# I created a grpc with spring boot using libraries from the "io.grpc" repository to generate my classes, I just wanted your opinion

Tags: spring-boot, grpc

I created a grpc with spring boot using libraries from the "io.grpc" repository to generate my classes, I just wanted your opinion am I doing it the right way? I'll post my classes and you guys give me feedback. OK?

My Controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/item"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String printMessage(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
    ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("springboot", 31217)
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();

    HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceBlockingStub stub
            = HelloServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

    HelloResponse helloResponse = stub.hello(HelloRequest.newBuilder()
            .setFirstName("Rafael")
            .setLastName("Fernando")
            .build());


    channel.shutdown();
    return helloResponse.getGreeting();
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class HelloServiceImpl extends HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceImplBase {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void hello(
            HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<HelloResponse> responseObserver) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", request.getFirstName());
        map.put("lastName", request.getLastName());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String jsonString;

        try {
            jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        HelloResponse response = HelloResponse.newBuilder()
                .setGreeting(jsonString)
                .build();

        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();

    }
}
```

My spring boot aplication:

```
  @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    
        public static void main(String[] args){
    
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            Server server = ServerBuilder
                    .forPort(31217)
                    .addService(new HelloServiceImpl()).build();
    
            server.start();
            server.awaitTermination();
        

    }
}
```

My class configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter(
                JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields(),
                JsonFormat.printer().omittingInsignificantWhitespace()
        );
    }
}
```

My HelloService.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
package com.example.demo;

message HelloRequest {
    string firstName = 1;
    string lastName = 2;
}

message HelloResponse {
    string greeting = 1;
}

service HelloService {
    rpc hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

My spring project works fine on kubernetes. In your opinion, is the structure right? another thing i wanted to know more about is the interceptors

Comment: The answer depends on what's your goal, can you edit your question explaining it? Here you have a REST endpoint wrapping a gRPC service. If that was your intention, looks ok. On the other hand, if your intention was to implement a pure gRPC client-service you have a conceptual misconception that I can elaborate on an answer.

Comment: Actually I think my question was wrong I want to know how to create GRPC endpoints like this controller in the question but I think my endpoint is itself
`service HelloService` is it right? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes that's right. So your goal here was to get a pure gRPC client and service running without the REST endpoint?

Comment: you are right i want to create pure grpc without rest api

Comment: @RafaelSouza I have updated my answer. I believe it will be helpful for you.
We should not mixup gRPC and Rest for production. But just for basic understanding it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

When working with gRPC there is no such thing as an endpoint so you don't need to declare a mapping. The equivalent to a REST endpoint in gRPC is the Remote Procedure itself.

So, by having this in your `@SpringBootApplication` class:

```
    Server server = ServerBuilder
            .forPort(31217)
            .addService(new HelloServiceImpl()).build();

    server.start();
    server.awaitTermination();
```

You already have a gRPC service serving calls.

---

Concerning interceptors, from a server point of view, you can think of them similarly to a REST interceptor in Spring-boot but instead of implementing `HandlerInterceptor` these need to implement gRPC's `ServerInterceptor`. You can intercept both responses and requests.

You can also add interceptors to your clients by having classes implementing `ClientInterceptor`. Both server/client interceptors can be registered globally (all incoming/outgoing calls go through it) or you can achieve a per-service/client style too but it requires some sort of a trick.

In any case, interceptors are chained and run in reverse order in which they were added. So `intercept(InterceptorA.class, InterceptorB.class)` will run in this order: `InterceptorB -> InterceptorA -> Service`

Here's an example from the official gRPC examples repository showcasing a JWT authentication interceptor:

```
public class JwtServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

  private JwtParser parser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(Constant.JWT_SIGNING_KEY);

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
      Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
    String value = metadata.get(Constant.AUTHORIZATION_METADATA_KEY);

    Status status = Status.OK;
    if (value == null) {
      status = Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Authorization token is missing");
    } else if (!value.startsWith(Constant.BEARER_TYPE)) {
      status = Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Unknown authorization type");
    } else {
      Jws<Claims> claims = null;
      // remove authorization type prefix
      String token = value.substring(Constant.BEARER_TYPE.length()).trim();
      try {
        // verify token signature and parse claims
        claims = parser.parseClaimsJws(token);
      } catch (JwtException e) {
        status = Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription(e.getMessage()).withCause(e);
      }
      if (claims != null) {
        // set client id into current context
        Context ctx = Context.current()
            .withValue(Constant.CLIENT_ID_CONTEXT_KEY, claims.getBody().getSubject());
        return Contexts.interceptCall(ctx, serverCall, metadata, serverCallHandler);
      }
    }

    serverCall.close(status, new Metadata());
    return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {
      // noop
    };
  }

}
```

and here how it's being attached globally (to all registered services) in the server start method:

```
  private void start() throws IOException {
    server = Grpc.newServerBuilderForPort(port, InsecureServerCredentials.create())
        .addService(new GreeterImpl())
        .intercept(new JwtServerInterceptor())  // add the JwtServerInterceptor
        .build()
        .start();
    logger.info("Server started, listening on " + port);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // Use stderr here since the logger may have been reset by its JVM shutdown hook.
        System.err.println("*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down");
        AuthServer.this.stop();
        System.err.println("*** server shut down");
      }
    });
  }
```

You can check the full example (among others) [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/31321562ee60c50dd34756b8071f21bc1723ac78/examples/example-jwt-auth/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/jwtauth).

Comment: I am creating an api in spring boot to access in android can i call the native grpc in android? do you have an example there? @Alejandro Lorefice Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I get your question. Check if you can find what you're looking for in the official docs on gRPC and Android-> https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/android/